# How to convert the string 2012 , December, 15 to a Datatime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I will get the String "2012" then "December" at first time

In the following get the string `1,15, 30`

I should convert them into  `Datetime` object

2012-12-01

2012-12-15

2012-12-30

How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date.strptime('2012 December', '%Y %B')
#=> Sat, 01 Dec 2012

date = Date.strptime('2012 December 10', '%Y %B %d')
#=> Mon, 10 Dec 2012

date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#=> "2012-12-10"
```

Comment: Here is your Happy new year Gift in SO.. <upvote> :)

Answer (score 0):

You have this string:

```
[1] pry(main)> str = "2012 December 1,15, 30"
=> "2012 December 1,15, 30"
```

And you want to get three dates from it (1st, 15th and 30th of December. First at all, get the year, month and days from this string:

```
[2] pry(main)> m = /(?'year'\d*)\s(?'month'[a-zA-Z]*)(?'days'[\d, ]*)/.match str
=> #<MatchData
 "2012 December 1,15, 30"
 year:"2012"
 month:"December"
 days:" 1,15, 30">
```

Then split the `days` to and array and iterate on it to convert the days with year and month to `Date` object (you can use `Date.strptime` as shivam showed above or `Time.parse`):

```
[10] pry(main)> require 'time'
=> true
[11] pry(main)> m[:days].split(',').collect {|day| Time.parse "#{m[:year]} #{m[:month]} #{day}"}
=> [2012-12-01 00:00:00 +0100,
 2012-12-15 00:00:00 +0100,
 2012-12-30 00:00:00 +0100]
```